# Importing a .json file local to create a treemap within vue js

Tags: html, json, vue.js, import

I am trying to import a .json file into my vue js project and then create a treemap based on the data.

my .json file looks like this

```
{
    "warehouses":[
        {
            "id":4,
            "name":"Goimek",
            "itemCount":354,
            "idParent":0,
            "nameParent":"",
            "locationInfo":[
            {
                "id":19,
                "name":"Puerta 4",
                "itemCount":354
            }],
            "warehouseChildrenInfo":[]
        },
        {
            "id":5,
            "name":"Karpa",
            "itemCount":167,
            "idParent":0,
            "nameParent":"",
            "locationInfo":[
            {
                "id":24,
                "name":"Karpa",
                "itemCount":167
            }],
            "warehouseChildrenInfo":[]
        },
        {
            "id":6,
            "name":"Wec",
            "itemCount":145,
            "idParent":0,
            "nameParent":"",
            "locationInfo":[
            {
                "id":25,
                "name":"WEC",
                "itemCount":115
            }],
            "warehouseChildrenInfo":[
            {
                "id":1009,
                "name":"BIGUMETRIK",
                "itemCount":30,
                "idParent":0,
                "nameParent":"",
                "locationInfo":[
                {
                    "id":1015,
                    "name":"BIGUMETRIK",
                    "itemCount":30
                }],
                "warehouseChildrenInfo":[]
            }]
        },

        {
            "id":1037,
            "name":"PROVEEDOR",
            "itemCount":10,
            "idParent":0,
            "nameParent":"",
            "locationInfo":[
            {
                "id":1553,
                "name":"PROVEEDOR Lehenetsitako kokapena",
                "itemCount":0
            },
            {
                "id":1554,
                "name":"PIKUMEK S.L",
                "itemCount":0
            },
            {
                "id":1555,
                "name":"TENKOR S.L",
                "itemCount":10
            },
            {
                "id":1556,
                "name":"ZUMELTXU S.L",
                "itemCount":0
            }],
            "warehouseChildrenInfo":[]
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is how im importing it

```
import warehouses from './warehouses.json'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'My first tree map',
      warehouses : warehouses
    }
  }
}
```

I then just try and display the data by doing this in a div

```
<div v-for="(warehouse,index) in warehouses" :key ="index" >{{warehouse.id }}</div>
```

but it doesn't display anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you check whether you can `console.log(warehouses)` in your `mounted()` hook for example?

Comment: Web browser don't allow work with files like in c, php and others. You may write ajax request which get a json response from server, further you need to parse it and put to your data attribute. After that you can use it in you `v-for`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your JSON from a js file in vue. Here is a sandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/read-json-file-k6pdc?file=/src/App.vue) for your JSON.